# PayPal Classic API - PaymentStatus NULL

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to Integrate the PayPal Classic API, but sometimes I'm receiving PayementStatus = NULL. 
This is a complete received response in JSON Format :

```
{"Amount":{"currencyID":125,"value":"20.00"},"AVSCode":"X","CVV2Code":"M","TransactionID":"0UU739590K678273P","PendingReason":null,"PaymentStatus":null,"FMFDetails":null,"ThreeDSecureResponse":null,"PaymentAdviceCode":null,"Timestamp":"2013-06-11T17:58:23Z","Ack":0,"CorrelationID":"a527c5481747","Errors":[],"Version":"98.0","Build":"6202528"}
```

Is it normal to receive a NULL value on payementStatus even the Ack = 0 and there is no errors and also I'm revceiving the TransactionID ???

Thank you for your help, I'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based On PayPal Support.
The field that need to be Checked here is ACK Field. 
If ACK is Success or SuccessWithWarning.
This is sufficient to say that the Payment succeed.